Create PopupMenuEntry from a List
Not finding a solution that fit to my problem I'll ask to SO for help.
I'm stuck in this problem that probably has a simple answer but I cannot see it right now.
I've a List of properties to be used to create a PopupmenuEntry with its PopupMenuItem
List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuItems = [{
      'value': 'edit',
      'iconData': const Icon(Icons.edit),
      'text': delegate.edit
    },
    {
      'value': 'playlists',
      'iconData': const Icon(Icons.playlist_play),
      'text': delegate.playlists
    },
    {
      'value': 'remove',
      'iconData': const Icon(Icons.remove),
      'text': delegate.remove
    }];

I want to iterate the list to build PopupMenuEntry. Something like
...
            trailing: PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (context) =>
                return menuItems.map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((e) => {
                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: e.key,
                    child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                             e.IconData,
                             Text(e.text)
                          ]
                       )
                  ,)
                }) 
                )

But throws a "The return type 'Iterable<PopupMenuEntry>' isn't a 'List<PopupMenuEntry<_>>" and I'm not able to find a solution

You can access map values directly, then remember to use toList to actually return a list of widgets
PopupMenuButton(
          itemBuilder: (context) =>
             menuItems.map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((e) =>  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: e["value"],
                child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                         e["iconData"],
                         Text(e["text"])
                      ]
                   )
              ,)
            ).toList()
            ),

Result on browser:


